# SQL Server time zones

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue with multiple applications I am using and I wanted to just make sure SQL Server is using the correct time...

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME(),               --2015-08-12 17:33:10.4796706
       SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),         --2015-08-12 17:33:10.4796706 +01:00
       SYSUTCDATETIME(),            --2015-08-12 16:33:10.4796706
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,           --2015-08-12 17:33:10.473
       GETDATE(),                   --2015-08-12 17:33:10.473
       GETUTCDATE()                 --2015-08-12 16:33:10.477
```

now as you can see there are 2 keywords that display as 1 hour less than the time I ran the query (17:33)

**is this displaying as you would expect?**

*To me this is wrong*

If it is wrong where can I change it? however if this is correct could someone explain why the 2 results are displaying an hour less than I would expect?

Thanks for the help, and to clarify I am based in the UK (UTC+00:00) is what it should say

Comment: it's correct... you can see from the 2nd line that your local is +1 of UTC, so when you call a UTC function you get an hour less

Comment: You're currently in a timezone that's using an offset of +1 against UTC? (E.g. British Summer Time) Why would you expect all functions to return exactly the same value (why would multiple functions exist?)?

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing this up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are based in an UTC+1 country. Consider moving out to a UTC+0 country if you still want to fix it ;)

Comment: im actually based in the UK, which is why this baffles me when it says UTC +1

Comment: Daylight Saving Time (DST) (Summer)

Comment: my applications don't seem to recognise this and its giving me a right headache haha!!

Answer (score 1):

SYSUTCDATETIME() and GETUTCDATE() return UTC datetimes and you are at +01:00 to UTC. This is correct.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx